# How To speed up mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I'm newbie in mongo databases, curenttly crating web app that use this

```
db.element.aggregate([{
  "$match": {
    "versions.branch": branch
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "$or": [{
      "doctype": "10921"
    }, {
      "doctype": "10926"
    }, {
      "doctype": "10943"
    }, {
      "doctype": "10945"
    }, {
      "doctype": "13162"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1521"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15281"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15282"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15283"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15284"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15291"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15372"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15431"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1545"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1550"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1551"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1555"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15514"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15516"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15517"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15518"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15519"
    }, {
      "doctype": "1553"
    }, {
      "doctype": "15542"
    }, {
      "doctype": "17402"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19009"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19055"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19073"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19082"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19083"
    }, {
      "doctype": "19812"
    }, {
      "doctype": "2134"
    }, {
      "doctype": "2400"
    }, {
      "doctype": "2401"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "prefix": {
      "$ne": "500"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$sort": {
    "id": 1
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$versions"
}, {
  "$match": {
    "versions.branch": branch
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$versions.labels"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$toUpper": "$_id"
    },
    "id": {
      "$addToSet": "$product_name"
    },
    "max": {
      "$max": "$versions.name"
    },
    "author": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.author"
    },
    "labels": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.labels"
    },
    "branch": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.branch"
    },
    "level": {
      "$addToSet": "$level"
    },
    "vob": {
      "$addToSet": "$vob"
    },
    "Name": {
      "$addToSet": "$_id"
    },
    "is_product": {
      "$addToSet": "$is_product"
    },
    "prefix": {
      "$addToSet": "$prefix"
    },
    "decclass": {
      "$addToSet": "$doctype"
    },
    "product_number": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.product_number"
    },
    "status": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.status"
    },
    "revision": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.revision"
    },
    "variant": {
      "$addToSet": "$versions.variant"
    }
  }
}, ])
```

web app is slow, and want to speed up , can you suggest me what to do, Which indexes to create, is order of query good ? or any other sugesttion . I created index

```
db.element.ensureIndex({product_name: 1, doctype: 1, prefix: 1})
```

shoud I use compund index or other? Also when    I tried to create index

```
db.element.ensureIndex({versions.branch: 1, doctype: 1, prefix: 1})
```

> ```
> Thu Jun 20 09:45:54.983 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
> ```

Comment: Why don't you use a $in query for that $or? And combine the matches so an index can be used fully?

Comment: what is difference , is $in or $or faster, I could use $in ....

Comment: $in will be 100x faster, an $or is like making the query of each clause in parallel, it is quite slow, plus index usage is not as optimal as $in

Comment: can you expllai in more details how to use $in instead or, and how to create index for that case??

Comment: Change your first three matches to: `{"versions.branch": branch, doctype: {$in: [list_of_all_ids]}, "prefix": { "$ne": "500" }}` and then make a compouind index on those three fields. Also when making an index you need: `db.element.ensureIndex({"versions.branch": 1, doctype: 1, prefix: 1})` on the subdocument field

Comment: THX :)), you're the best , it's much faster

Answer (score 6):

A few things that you can do here:

First of all, use an $in instead of an $or.

Secondly, MongoDB can *only* use an index for your first match, so you will have to decide (by trying it out) which of the two matches is better. The goal is to have as fast a query, and as fewer documents going through your pipeline. For that you do the following things:

First, create the three indexes:

```
db.element.ensureIndex( { 'versions.branch' : 1 } );
db.element.ensureIndex( { 'doctype' : 1 } );
db.element.ensureIndex( { 'prefix' : 1 } );
```

Then run the following three queries and notice the "cursor", "n", "nScanned" and "ms" fields:

```
branch = "nameofbranch"; // guessing here
db.element.find( "versions.branch": branch ).explain();
db.element.find( "doctype" { $in: [ "15281", "15282" .... ] } ).explain();
db.element.find( "prefix": { $ne: "500" } ).explain();
```

For the last query, you will note that "cursor" is "BasicCursor", because a $ne query can not use the index.

The other two will show you various values for "ms", "n" and "nScanned". "ms" is the time it took to run the query. If this is approximately the same, then look at the difference between the "n" and "nScanned" values. I am going to expect and guess that the difference for the "versions.branch" query is 0. For the "doctype" query it might be different.
If the "ms" is not approximately the same put the $match which was the fastest first as $match clause in your aggregation pipeline.

If the speed ("ms") is both the same, check the "n" values. If the "n" for the "prefix" query is say "5" and the "n" for the "versions.branch" query is "500" then that means that the result of the "prefix" query is better, as fewer documents are returned. In that case, put that as your first $match clause in aggregate. If the "versions.branch" is a lot less, use that one as first $match clause.